# Which VNCServer port to use to connect to home computer?

Tags: ports

I want to connect to my home computer from the library via a VNCServer located on my home computer, but I'm pretty sure the library blocks the port 5900 and higher.  Can I change the port which my vncserver listens to get around the blocked port?  Which port probably would allow me to get around the library's port blocking? Is there anyway I can test which ports are open at the library?

Answer (score 0):

The VNCServer is running on your home machine, it shouldn't matter what ports are blocked in the library.   You are in the library(with your laptop?).  The library blocking ports 5900+ only stops incoming connections (coming into the library) from using those ports not from you connecting to other device's port on that device's port number.

You can check from the library if your port/IP is visible using things like : http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: Yes, I am in the library on my laptop.   I can't seem to connect to my computer from that specific library, but I can connect from other remote locations.   I thought it was because there was some port blocking going on.

Comment: Can you 'ping' your home computer's IP address?   The library DNS may have some domains blocked.   You may also have to setup some kind of proxy to go through the library infrastructure.